# All requests are http inside rails app deployed on heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have an app and its URL is `https://example.sample.com`. But when I log inside the app using rails logger
`Rails.logger.info request.base_url`
It shows `http://example.sample.com`. Why is it like that?

Answer (score 0):

You need to ensure ssl using `config.force_ssl` in your `config/environments/production.rb` file:

```rb
config.force_ssl = true
```